Normalizing search scores on Azure AI Search
I have an index on AI Search that contains one term in English (e.g. "white wine", "grapes", "chocolate cake", ...) per document. I have a vector field. Indexing has run without problems for 100k documents.
My use case is to find the closest term to one entered by the user and give a score to the match (0-100%).
When I run the following query on Search Explorer on Azure Portal for my index:
{
  "search": "Winery products",
  "count": true,
  "vectorQueries": [
    {
      "kind": "text",
      "text": "Winery products",
      "fields": "vectorTextEnglish"
    }
  ]
}

I get the right results. Please note top score is 0.031:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://me.search.windows.net/indexes('myindex')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "@odata.count": 75,
  "@search.nextPageParameters": {
    "select": "chunk_id,Term,MyReference,parent_id",
    "count": true,
    "skip": 50,
    "vectorQueries": [
      {
        "kind": "text",
        "k": null,
        "oversampling": null,
        "fields": "vectorTextEnglish",
        "vector": [],
        "text": "Winery products",
        "url": null,
        "base64Image": null,
        "exhaustive": null,
        "weight": null,
        "filterOverride": null,
        "threshold": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.0317540317773819,
      "chunk_id": "xxxx",
      "Term": "Alcoholic wines",
      "MyReference": "00123",
      "parent_id": "yyyyy"
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 0.03159204125404358,
      ...
    },

However, if I ask a random string asdfjiwefowfwe I get a very similar score 0.030.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://me.search.windows.net/indexes('myindex')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "@odata.count": 93,
  "@search.nextPageParameters": {
    "select": "chunk_id,Term,MyReference,parent_id",    
    "count": true,
    "skip": 50,
    "vectorQueries": [
      {
        "kind": "text",
        "k": null,
        "oversampling": null,
        "fields": "vectorTextEnglish",
        "vector": [],
        "text": "asdfjiwefowfwe",
        "url": null,
        "base64Image": null,
        "exhaustive": null,
        "weight": null,
        "filterOverride": null,
        "threshold": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.03083491325378418,
      "chunk_id": "xxxxxx",
      "Term": "Ash",
      "MyReference": "00422",
      "parent_id": "yyyyy"
    },
    {
      "@search.score": 0.029877368360757828,
      ...
    },

I would like to normalize the score of the match from 0-100, but I don't understand how does a random string get the same score as a good match. Anyone can help me understand and guide me how to give a higher score if the match is good and 0 for random strings?
I tried setting some thresholds, but since scores are so close to each other, it is impossible. I tried with semantic ranking but it is even more confusing, these random strings get 1.8 reranking score while a perfect match is perhaps 2.4.

check this doc for ranking

Use the parameter "debug": "all" in your request. Then you will get in the response a new property like "vectorSimilarity": "0.998" that goes from 0 to  1. In most cases you can then ignore keyword score, since vector search is very accurate. Semantic ranking is an overkill for most use cases.

To address the issue of similar scores in Azure AI Search when working with large datasets, you can add a scoring profile to the vector index.
I referred to this guide on creating a vector index in Azure AI Search.

Using scoring profiles enables you to apply weights to relevant fields.
For example, you might define a scoring profile that gives more weight to matches in specific fields, making them more influential than less relevant fields.

I followed this documentation to add scoring profiles in Azure AI Search.

In your case, you should add weight to the Term field, as shown in the image below.

The sample scoring profile, named sampath, assigns a weight of 5 to the Term field using a custom scoring function.
"scoringProfiles": [
    {
        "name": "sampath",
        "functionAggregation": "sum",
        "text": {
            "weights": {
                "Term": 5
            }
        },
        // "functions": [
        //   {
        //       "fieldName": "Term",
        //       "interpolation": "linear",
        //       "type": "tag",
        //       "boost": 5,
        //       "freshness": null,
        //       "magnitude": null,
        //       "distance": null,
        //       "tag": {
        //           "tagsParameter": "tag"
        //       }
        //   }
        // ]
    }
]



JSON query:
{
  "search": "Winery products",
  "scoringProfile": "boostRelevantMatches",
  "count": true
}

Output:


I don't see any difference in the output with scoring profile as you define it. I guess you need to add 2 elements, the vector (x1) and the term (x5), but still not really what I expected to see. I think this document might be a better lead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/hybrid-search-ranking

Since vector search scores aren't necessarily within a predictable range, you can apply manual normalization. For example, you could scale the scores to a 0-100 range.First, retrieve the minimum and maximum scores across all query results.Then, normalize the scores based on this range .This will map the lowest score to 0 and the highest score to 100.Use Semantic Ranking for Better Relevance.

Semantic ranker is a collection of query-side capabilities that improve the quality of an initial BM25-ranked or RRF-ranked search result
